# How to verify nonces in bulk?

Tags: admin, metabox, nonce

Hey I'm relatively new to WP, and I'm trying to get a handle on nonces since they're a good security check. I'm having difficulty verifying my nonces in `save_post` however.

The checks fail on the `$_POST` checks. When var_dumping the $_POST variable, I can see my nonces and post field names, but I cannot verify them in bulk. When I remove the verification, everything works fine.

[link to gist](https://gist.github.com/spkellydev/8f3de7baf831cbfc55c2eebad50c3b9d)

This is my save function:

```
function mdw_save($post_id)
{
    $metas = array(
        's_1_title',
        's_1_desc',
        's_2_title',
        's_2_desc',
        's_1_image',
        's_2_image',
    );
    foreach ($metas as $meta) {
        if (!isset($_POST[$meta])) {
            return;
        }

        if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST[$meta . '_nonce'], 'mdw_save')) {
            return;
        }

        if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
            return $post_id;
        }

        update_post_meta($post_id, $meta, $_POST[$meta]);
    }

    return $post_id;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a nonce for every field, a single nonce should suffice

This is because a nonce isn't tied to a field, it's tied to a request, and verifies that you did indeed intend to press update, or click a link, submit a form, etc

As an example, back in the days of MySpace, they didn't verify intention on the logout script, so you could put an image tag on your profile and set the `src` as the logout URL. Anybody who visited your profile would get logged out.

If MySpace had added a nonce, they'd have been able to verify if you'd arrived at the URL intentionally, or by accident/malice.

As a result, you should never need to verify multiple nonces at the same time, you only need 1.